# How to get this textfield from a WebBrowser Element

Tags: c#, vb.net, webbrowser-control

It's about the first textfield on this site: https://www.xing.com/

This is its source code of the textfield:

```
<input class="text" name="first_name" type="text" value="" autocomplete="on" tabindex="10" placeholder="Vorname" data-error-message="Geben Sie hier Ihren Vornamen ein.">
```

Since there is no ID tag I can't use

```
WebBrowser.Document.GetElementById
```

so I tried this:

```
    Dim theElementCollection As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All
    For Each element As HtmlElement In theElementCollection
        If element.GetAttribute("name") = "first_name" Then
            MsgBox("Found the element :)")
        End If
    Next
```

Even that did not work. I don't really understand this. I thought WebBrowser.Document.All returns every single element.

Comment: There is `GetElementsByName` (returns collection)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Nope Alex, there is GetElementsByTagName and I tried that. Didn't work either.

Comment: [`WebBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelementcollection.getelementsbyname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I tried WebBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("first_name")     and got an empty list. Really strange